# Can someone identify these marks on the bottom of a blue porcelain bowl? (Characters identified: 中王國 賈泊氏)

Tags: translation, character-identification

Can someone please identify these marks on the bottom of a bowl?

賈中
伯王
氏國

[image]

Comment: Read it vertically and from right to left, so it's 中王國賈伯氏.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably `中王国 贾泊氏`.

And I did some search and found that this picture should come from some antique forums. However there's no canonical record for it. This piece of porcelain is probably *modern made*. On [this site](http://bbs.cntv.cn/thread-13758851-1-1.html), a person said:

> It's "fake scholars will finally subjugate the nation".

(read left to right instead of right to left)

(假博士终亡国, which has the same pronunciation as the original words)

Answer (score 0):

中王国 贾泊氏,I think this might be a reasonable way to read them